# nginx configuratio : alias and 404 error

Tags: nginx, location, alias

My actual problem was that I wanted to make my "site.com/blog/index.php" direct to "/srvX/www/blog/caller/index.php". Althought it would be very straightforward to direct to "/srv/www/blog/index.php" using "root /srv/www/", that's not what I wanted. I discovered "alias", and it seem to do what I want.

1)First try :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    root /srv/www/blog/pages;
    index index.php;

    location /blog {
            alias /srv/www/blog/caller;
    }
}
```

There trying site.com/blog get me a 404 not found, and nothing pop into /var/log/nginx/error.log

1)Second try to know what happens :

If I change "alias /srv/www/blog/caller;" to a bad path, let say "alias /srvX/www/blog/caller;" I actually got the same behaviour in my browser, but 
I can see in /var/log/nginx/error.log :

[error] 7229#0: *1 "/srvX/www/blog/caller/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.200, server: 192.168.1.221, request: "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.221"

Conclusion : I don't know what's hapenning there : it seem clear that nginx get the file in my first try, but it sends the 404 error to the browser with no reason I could think of, while when specyfiyng a wrong path, it tells me right away. :/*

---

**edit**

Well, I found the solution. Basically it totally works from nginx, the problem was from php-fpm who lose his mind when using alias into nginx. What you need to do is doing a sublocation of aliased locations adding :

```
             location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            }
```

Now it works.
The fact that nginx was giving a 404 error without anything in the nginx's logs, was that php-fpm was the one failing to serve.

Comment: What happens when you try `site.com/blog/index.php`? Or maybe try simple html ("Hello world")! Could you please copy full `nginx.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have no instructions on how to deal with the php script. To solve this issue the following:

Add the following code to your nginx.conf file within the server tags or if you have created that in your conf.d folder add it to that file.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

That will solve that problem but also in the file:

> /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

Ensure that listen.owner is set to listen.owner = nginx

Ensure that listen.group is set to listen.group = nginx

Restart both services and it should work.

If not ensure your document root and all files with that directory are owned by the user nginx and the group nginx.

If not you can do this by using the following:

> chown -R nginx:nginx documentroot

And keep doing that but adding /* each time until you reach an error.

Hope everything works out for you!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't gave all my config, but the php bit is there and works already. Also the permissions are fin too. It's not that, I'm really confident it's not that : because it already work. My actual problem is really getting nginx to serve my alias properly.